# How to convert Kilobytes to Megabytes or gigabytes through terminal?

Tags: command-line

I try to find the size of my disk, so i runned the below command

```
$ sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda
976762584
```

It shows like above. I think the size(`976762584`) of the disk is shown  in kilobytes. How do i convert the value to megabytes or gigabytes through terminal for better understanding?

Comment: This would do the trick: `df -h /`. Display the size of `/` in a `-h`uman readable format.

Comment: fdisk -s is also deprecated so probably better to use ```blockdev --getsize64```

Comment: @blade19899 that will get the size of the partition not the whole disk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The shell does fixed-width integer arithmetic with no check for  overflow.  So, when doing a calculation that might involve either large numbers or fractions, `bc` is a good choice.  To get megabytes:

```
$ echo "scale=2; $(sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda6) / 1024" | bc
13641.75
```

To get gigabytes:

```
$ echo "scale=2; $(sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda6) / 1024^2" | bc
12.70
```

The assignment `scale=2` tells `bc` to display two decimal places.

Comment: I like using herestrings for cases like this: `bc <<<"scale=2; $(sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda6) / 1024^2"`

Answer (score 16):

[`numfmt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html#numfmt-invocation) (part of [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)) can be used here:

```
$ sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda
976762584

$ sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.2f"
931.52MiB
```

Comment: Including the output from the command in your answer would make it more complete.

Comment: @Samir adding the output as an example here only makes sense if the output of `sudo fdisk s /dev/sda` and `sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.2f"` agree. Now we have an example where the outputs have no relation to each other. `numfmt` isn't going to convert `488386584` to `931.52MiB`

Comment: Yes you're correct, I updated it with the correct number.

Answer (score 5):

#### In awk

To find the size of the disk in Megabytes,

```
$ sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda | awk '{$1=$1/1024; print $1,"MB";}'
953870 MB
```

To find the size of the disk in Gigabytes,

```
$ sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda | awk '{$1=$1/(1024^2); print $1,"GB";}'
931.513 GB
```

Comment: instead of `sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda` you can use `df | grep ^\/dev.*/\$`

Comment: @DeanRather `sudo fdisk` was the project scope defined in question.

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool called units, which can be used for units conversion:

```bash
$ units -o "%.0f" -t "4 gibibytes" "mebibytes"
4096
```

It is available as a package via `apt install units`.

It is a fairly standard tool, that can be found installed by default on various other UNIX-like systems (e.g., [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/)). Keep in mind that units(1) syntax may differ across implementations available on various operating systems. Here's the same conversion but this time with [FreeBSD units(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/units):

```sh
$ units -o "%0.f" -t "4 gigabytes" "megabytes"
4096
```

Answer (score 3):

If the size is given in Kilobytes, you need to calculate through Bash built-in expressions.
Assuming block size = 512B, you have to type:

```
echo $((`fdisk -s /dev/sda`*512/1024))
```

This will show disk size in KiB. To go further, just add `/1024` to the end of expression:

```
echo $((`fdisk -s /dev/sda`*512/1024/1024))
```

This will show disk size in MiB and so on.

Comment: Nicely done.  As a minor note, the `$[...]` format has been deprecated and, as `man bash` says, "will be removed in upcoming versions."  The currently preferred format for shell arithmetic is `$((...))`.

Comment: @John1024 thanks for the note. Didn't guess that double brackets syntax is appropriate.

Comment: Copy and pasting two commands generate error because `sudo` is missing. Also the unit of measure doesn't print out.

Comment: measurement is wrong.

Comment: but you could do ```echo $((($(cat /sys/block/sda/size)*512)/1024**3))GB```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this natively with Bash and pseudo-floating point numbers. Define this function in your `~/.bashrc` and reopen your terminal:

```bash
function BytesToHuman() {

    # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1/259254#259254

    read StdIn

    b=${StdIn:-0}; d=''; s=0; S=(Bytes {K,M,G,T,E,P,Y,Z}iB)
    while ((b > 1024)); do
        d="$(printf ".%02d" $((b % 1024 * 100 / 1024)))"
        b=$((b / 1024))
        let s++
    done
    echo "$b$d ${S[$s]}"

} # BytesToHuman ()
```

Now test it:

```bash
$ sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda
976762584

$ sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda | BytesToHuman
931.51 MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bash or Zsh, this function will perform the calculation for you.  Additionally, if `-si` is the first argument, calculations are performed in SI units.

```bsh
size () {
    local -a units
    local -i scale
    if [[ "$1" == "-si" ]]
    then
        scale=1024
        units=(B KiB MiB GiB TiB EiB PiB YiB ZiB)
        shift
    else
        scale=1000
        units=(B KB MB GB TB EB PB YB ZB)
    fi
    local -i unit=0
    if [ -z "${units[0]}" ]
    then
        unit=1
    fi
    local -i whole=${1:-0}
    local -i remainder=0
    while (( whole >= $scale ))
    do
        remainder=$(( whole % scale ))
        whole=$((whole / scale))
        unit=$(( $unit + 1 ))
    done
    local decimal
    if [ $remainder -gt 0 ]
    then
        local -i fraction="$(( (remainder * 10 / scale)))"
        if [ "$fraction" -gt 0 ]
        then
            decimal=".$fraction"
        fi
    fi
    echo "${whole}${decimal}${units[$unit]}"
}
```

For example:

```
$ size 1
1B

$ size 100
100B

$ size 999
999B

$ size 1000
1KB

$ size 4096
4KB

$ size -si 1000
1000B

$ size -si 1024
1KiB

$ size -si $(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 ))
1MiB

$ size -si $(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 - 1 ))
1023.9KiB

$ size -si $(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 ))
1MiB

$ size -si $(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 + 1 ))
1MiB

$ size -si $(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 + ( 1024 * 512 ) ))
1.5MiB

$ size -si $(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 + ( 1024 * 1024 ) ))
2MiB

$ size -si $(( 1 * 1024 * 1024 + ( 1024 * 1024 - 1 ) ))
1.9MiB
```

This is also compatible with e.g. `sort -h`.

```
$ { size 32; size 32000; size 35 } | sort -h
32B
35B
32KB
```